# What does addplot+ do exactly?

Tags: pgfplots

So using `\addplot+` gives specific points on my curve vs `\addplot` which just gives me a curve? How does `\addplot+` select the points it graphs etc?

Comment: When you use `\addplot`, the default styles are over written. When `\addplot+` the changes we make are appended not replaced.

Comment: @harish: sounds like an answer, my friend :)

Comment: @cmhughes Hi Chris, Long time...... :-) Looks like you are busy. :). Answer added. Thanks.

Comment: It uses `/.style` or `/.append style` handlers depending on the `+` sign

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer for your question lies in section 3.3.2, page 24, of `pgfplots` manual:

[image]

So, to be brief, When you add many `\addplot` lines inside the `axis` environment like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot {x};
      \addplot {x-1};
      \addplot {x-2};
      \addplot {x-3};
      \addplot {x-4};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Every `\addplot` directive receives a pre-defined style (line color, marker style etc) through a pre-defined `cycle list` that is automatically chosen depending on the index of the current `\addplot` instruction. If you want to add some of your styles manually (like I want red colour instead of blue, say), you can add them through options to `\addplot` like `\addplot[<your options>]`. Now the question is whether you want your own style (your options) to be appended to or replace one of these cycle lists assigned. This is decided by the `+` sign. If you use `\addplot+ [<your options>]`, your style is *appended* to and by `\addplot[<your options>]` , `your options` will *replace* the assigned cycle list.